# Create CSV file with form data using HTML/javascript and saving it to DropBox on an iPad

Tags: javascript, forms, ipad, html, dropbox

I am attempting to create form to be used offline on an iPad using HTML5 and javascript.  I want to have a button that will create a CSV file (named by date and timestamp) of the form data and save it to the dropbox app (or something similar/google drive?).  I will then sync it at a future time, parse the data into a database so I can analyze the numbers.

I've been looking at searching for answers and guides, but I'm quite new, so I would appreciate any guidance.

One approach I've found is to create a form and create a javascript to create an URL using the  fields to create a DataURI that spits out a CSV file.  The user would then save this file to a Dropbox folder.

Would this be a good way to go about it or is there an easier way?

Thanks in advance!